# how to run a .NET Core project in 32-bit mode

Tags: .net-core

How can you force `dotnet` to run a project in 32-bit mode on a Windows 10 64-bit machine? Both `dotnet restore` and the `dotnet build` support a `--runtime` switch, e.g.:

```
dotnet restore --runtime win-x86
dotnet build --runtime win-x86
```

The `dotnet run` sub-command however does not support a `--runtime` switch.

Comment: It does have a `--configuration` switch to run an x86-only configuration. Arguably, that is what you should be using in `build` too.

Comment: @JeroenMostert How do I specify the platform with the `--configuration` switch?

Comment: You don't -- not directly. Your project should have a configuration that builds an x86-only version (as specified by the answer of J. Doe), and then you specify that configuration. If you can't or don't want to modify the build, you can use [`corflags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/corflags-exe-corflags-conversion-tool) to set the 32-bit flag on the main assembly after the fact (I'm not sure this works for .NET Core, however).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is a [runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) option for `dotnet run` now.

To execute as x86:

`dotnet run -r win-x86`

Comment: For an IIS hosted Core web API, you can run the DLL directly from the C:\Inetpub\WebAPI\ folder using dotnet webapi.dll, but if the API was targetting x86, you get the System.BadImageFormatException error. The run command does not let you execute the DLL directly. You have to specify the project, even if you use --no-build. Why is there not a version of dotnet.exe that can run a 32-bit DLL directly?

Answer (score 13):

[`dotnet run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run) does not have `--runtime`/`-r` support but dont give up bro, there is a  hope!

If you want only run in 32 bit you can easly use for example `dotnet your_app.dll` after build to 32 bit (by [`publish`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish) or [`build`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build)). `dotnet run` command running application from the source code

If you want force x86 in VS go to the `Properties > Build` and change `Platform target` from `Any CPU` to `x86`

Comment: This can be done manually by adding <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget> to the first PropertyGroup in the csproj, or using /p:PlatformTarget=x86  on the command line

Comment: doesn't work for me, if I do that the application crashes during startup (even with an empty .net core console application template set to 32 bit this way)

Comment: @Zarat, same happened with me... :(

Comment: This post helped me getting a web site project running via console (rather than IISExpress). It suggests creating a "Directory.Build.targets" file which changes the version of dotnet.exe is used once you've set your project to compile as x86.  https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/901#issuecomment-328307413