# Restart .NET AnyCPU exe with different bitness

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit

I have a .NET exe compiled for "AnyCPU", so it can theoretically run in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode (on a 64-bit operating system). Since my exe strongly interacts with MS Office, I need to run it with the same bitness *as the installed Office version*. (Please take this requirement as granted, I will gladly provide details in the comments, if you are interested.)

Now, I have thought up a solution for this, but it seems more complicated than necessary:

1. Compile two versions: MyExe32.exe and MyExe64.exe, targeting x86 and x64, respectively, instead of AnyCPU.
2. Create a launcher application Launcher.exe, which determines the bitness of the locally installed Office version (I know how to do that) and then starts MyExe32.exe or MyExe64.exe.

This would work, but I'd rather have a single, simple MyExe.exe with something like the following pseudo-code during start-up:

```
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess && IsOffice32BitInstalled)
{
    // restart myself in a 32-bit process instead of a 64-bit process
    ???  // <-- this is where I need help
}
```

Is that possible? If yes, how?

---

Notes: I know about the [CorFlags utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/ms164699(v=vs.80)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but I'd rather have a solution that does not require modifying the exe itself at runtime.

Comment: It's a well-thought-out and well-presented question.  I wish I knew how to help.

Comment: What about launcher which will use `CorFlags`?

Comment: If you're going to have an installation then you could just install the one you need, it's not likely to change after the initial setup.

Comment: Rather than a runtime thing, can you discover the Office bitness during install and perform a one time modification (corflags) of the exe? it's unlikely the bitness of office will change, so making it a one time mod of your app might suffice?

Comment: The other thing I wondered.. If a 32bit process launches your process, does it launch as 32bit? e.g. what happens if you ask c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe to launch your exe for you?  (I've never tried)

Comment: @rfmodulator, CaiusJard: Good idea, but, unfortunately, it's an internal tool residing on a network share, not something that is installed locally.

Comment: @CaiusJard: I tried that (both with cmd.exe and with explorer.exe from SysWOW64). Unfortunately, it still runs as 64-bit.

Comment: Is this for the `OLE-DB` drivers?

Comment: @rfmodulator: Mostly, yes. It's an automated build tool for MS Access applications. I know that there's an unsupported workaround to install both the 32 and the 64 bit version of the ACE driver on the same system, but I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Comment: Yeah... that doesn't sound any better than the solutions you've presented here.

Comment: I'm having the same issue (also for the OLE drivers). I did not find a solution for the problem yet, _but_ it appears that with recent Office versions, the 32 bit drivers always work. My access db library always runs in a 32 bit process, and I have not had any customer complaints about this not working. However, the Access DB driver is only required for reading old data sets from my application, and I don't know how many customers still need those.

Comment: What does your app do, Heinzi?where does the bitness come in re the drivers?

Comment: @CaiusJard The OLE drivers are installed with Office, and always in the bitness of the installed Office version. So if you want to use them, your app must run with the same bitness as the installed office version. At least that used to be the case when I was last checking on this.

Comment: Mmm, I recall having been subject to similar before but eventually I got sick of the battle and standardized the bitness of office (it also helped with some awful outlook plugin related to Sage Act!) including resolving [an amusing chicken and egg](https://superuser.com/questions/1557350/how-to-resolve-you-cannot-install-the-32-64-bit-version-of-microsoft-access-da/1557525) but then I went and rewrote the app to not need anything from office - am curious to know whether that's an option/how deeply intertwined Heinzi's/your app and office components are

Comment: @CaiusJard In my case, I use the access db format for data exchange. Newer versions of the app use Sqlite for the same, but for backwards compatibility, I still need to be able to read the old files.

Comment: @CaiusJard: We are developing/maintaining Access-based software (frontend only, the backend is SQL Server). The .NET tool in question is a custom-built build tool to automate all the steps required to create a deployment package for our Access-based applications. It automates Office to do stuff such as repairing/compacting/decompiling all databases, compiling the mde/accde files, bundling everything with the installer, etc.

Comment: I take it swapping the entire estate over to a common bitness is a bridge too far?

Comment: @CaiusJard: That's what we currently do (32-bit only). However, our customers are increasingly demanding that we support 64-bit Office too (and rightly so, it's 2022, after all), so we need to support both (for current customers who use 32-bit, and for new customers who use 64-bit).

Comment: BTW, I've worked around the problem in the mean time by fixing the tool to 32 bit and using the old "Jet" drivers instead of the new "ACE" drivers, since the former are always available for 32-bit processes. I can do that because we still use the "old" mdb format instead of the "new" accdb format. This allows me to postpone the issue.

Comment: Neat trick.. If it's per customer, and customers have consistent bitness it merhaps makes your proposed solution sensibly viable even giving customers just the relevant bitness one at a customer level.. I was also wondering if your launcher could download an AnyCPU to a temp folder, modify it for the appropriate bitness and run it; less maintenance for you perhaps.. But it might be what you were thinking in the ultimate sentence..

Answer (score 2):

Apparently I don't have reputation enough to post comments, so posting this as an answer instead.

If, as you say, you're deploying to an internal network, I'd recommend using a launcher *anwyay*.

That way users can have a single network shortcut to the launcher, that doesn't move around. The launcher can determine which bitness is required, *and* which is the latest release, and launch the EXE for that release.

If you allow users to go directly at the EXE, you will either encounter problems with users having the EXE opened, so you can't overwrite it, or have to create new user shortcuts for every release.

Comment: This is an answer, so you shouldn't need to apologise for not posting it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Is restarting via runtime parameter an option?

```
dotnet run -r win-x86
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63252884/18152293

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).